# What's the difference between id and place id in google map api result?

Tags: database, api, google-maps, location

[Here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=tehran&types=geocode&key=AIzaSyB_TPo7ZG0RQ_h1kdEMwvUhfJkQHAfyMl8) is an example result of google map api.

As you can see, there are two items which seem to be unique.

```
id: "4c45c924b261e2bb262360fb5a25d4b9a94088a7",

place_id: "ChIJf5Us9YQBjj8R0OohvHQms1U",
```

Well what's the difference between these? Should I store which one in my project's database to use it for later use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use place_id (id looks like a temporary identifier)

[Place IDs](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) :

> A place ID is a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place...
>
> You can use the same place ID across the Google Places API and a number of Google Maps APIs...
>
> You can store the place ID and use it to retrieve the same place details later...
>
> Place IDs are exempt from the caching restrictions stated in Section 10.5.d of the Google Maps APIs Terms of Service. You can therefore store place ID values for later use.

Comment: Be warned that Place IDs are slightly more [ephemeral](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#save-id) than one would hope.